# Calling a function that expects the address of an instance of itself with the this pointer

Tags: c++, function, this

I am trying to have a function that is handed an instance of the class that it belongs to. I know I can do it with the `this` pointer but I am not sure how to call that function. Any help is appreciated! This is my code:

ClassA.h

```
ClassA{
     public:
         int Send(Foo &myFoo, ClassB &classb);
}
```

ClassA.cpp

```
int ClassA::Send(Foo &myFoo, ClassB &classb)
{
...
}
```

ClassB.cpp

```
void function(const Foo &thisFoo){
 ClassA myClassA;
 int ret =  myClassA.Send(&thisFoo, *this);
}
```

I end up with this error:
no matching function for call to ‘ClassB::Send(const Foo*, ClassB&)’

EDIT: Thanks for the input! It works when I made ClassA expect a const Foo in Send().

ClassA.h

```
ClassA{
             public:
                 int Send(const Foo &myFoo, ClassB &classb);
        }
```

ClassA.cpp

```
int ClassA::Send(const Foo &myFoo, ClassB &classb)
{
...
}
```

ClassB.cpp

```
void function(const Foo &thisFoo){
 ClassA myClassA;
 int ret =  myClassA.Send(thisFoo, *this);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that makes sense?

Comment: 1) `function()` takes a `const Foo&`, and then tries to pass a non-const `Foo&` (well, that is, `Send()` takes a non-const `Foo&`, but you're giving it a pointer of type `const Foo*`, which is doubly problematic). 2) Does `ClassB` derive from `ClassA`?

Answer (score 1):

&thisFoo results in address of thisFoo object. It has type Foo*. 
You need  to do it this way:

```
int ret =  myClassA.Send(thisFoo, *this);
```

**Edit**: 
You cant call myClassA.Send() with thisFoo argument since thisFoo is declared as const reference.
So you have to either make thisFoo argument non-const, or (wich is kinda weird) pass a copy of it, or do a const_cast

Comment: except that `ClassA::Send` does not take a `ClassB` as second argument.

Comment: @juanchopanza Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DesmondHume There's nothing in the code posted that leads me to believe that. Then again, there's nothing in the code posted that makes much sense.